# UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync generated token does not work from other domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-webassembly

Im trying to create an identity provider, where a user logs in to the application (and is then redirected), and manages their account credentials, and which provides bearer tokens. Separately runs a Blazor WASM web application that manages the application logic, but also has an admin panel in which administrators can create users, reset passwords, manage roles/permissions, etc. This admin panel calls an API.

- The identity provider runs on https://localhost:5000
- The web application runs on https://localhost:5001
- The API on runs https://localhost:5002.

Now, when I create a user in this admin panel, the API is called, which sends a confirmation email that contains a URL containing the email confirmation token, generated by ASP.NET Identity's UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync. The token is generated by the API (localhost:5002) calling the class library, but the URL to confirm is to https://localhost:5000/Account/ConfirmEmail?UserId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&token=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy. When I click this link, I receive the message: `VerifyUserTokenAsync() failed with purpose: EmailConfirmation for user xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.` with the error message: "InvalidToken".

The identity provider runs ASP.NET Identity, IdentityServer4, and is written in ASP.NET Core 3.1. The application is written in Blazor (which is netstandard2.1), which then calls an API (ASP.NET Core 3.1), which calls a class library (ASP.NET Core 3.1). All projects use the same DatabaseContexts.

I've [tried](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/9887) setting

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Configuration["AppSettings:keydir"]))
    .SetApplicationName(Configuration["AppSettings:keyname"]);
```

in both the identity provider and the API, but no luck. I also tried setting:

```
services.AddDataProtection(options =>
    {
        options.ApplicationDiscriminator = "myapp";
    })
```

which is similar to this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22081

Im thinking it might be due to the extra class library I'm calling, do I have to set some DataProtection setting there?

Comment: I don't understand what did you do very well, You generate a confirmation  token from your Api and send that token to identity project to confirm user account ?

Comment: Yes. From my application I call an API that generates an email confirmation token, and emails this token incorporated in a URL to the user. The user then clicks this link, which takes it to the identity provider to confirm this token.

Comment: It's not a right way , you have to generate token from (identity provider https://localhost:5000 ) then create action link something like wat you said ( https://localhost:5000/Account/ConfirmEmail?UserId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&token=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy. )

Comment: @mohammadmahdiTalachi The workflow OP mentioned should be fine. Without any configuration your suggestion is fine, but OP mentioned DataProtection package, which helps you share tokens across multiple applications (by using same private key)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but it was a different problem, which I've described in my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The different projects were not the problem, neither was the dataprotection. Turned out I generated a confirmationtoken before I had created the user. This way the generated token is based on an empty securitystamp. Then in the other project, the usermanager validates the token against a token based on a non-null securitystamp, because now the user had been created. This of course yields an invalid token.